Connecting Flutter with Firebase
I recently heard about Project IDX and I have loved it so far. I have been using it to create Flutter apps. I have been using it for quite some time and wanted to see if I could even integrate Flutter and Firebase together and create an app. I am not good with both Flutter and Firebase as i just got started on them.
I saw a bit of tutorials here and there and saw that you had to create a project on Firebase and then use the command line to connect your flutter project. i have done that quite a few times. but recently when i tried to connect my flutter app to a firebase project i could not.
the problem rises whenever i run the firebase login command. that command is supposed to give you a link where you can get an authorization key. it used to work for me. but recently the link generated by the command does not work. simply put, the link does not load at all. what is wrong?
I tried creating new accounts for both firebase and IDX. i also tried cleaning my Flutter project and doing a reinstall of the firebase tools. nothing has fixed it so far.
